# Is it possible to spoof the browser's useragent using a local VPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, steam, google-accounts

Context: I'm trying to log in to my YouTube account on the Steam overlay browser but Google is flagging it as unsecure probably because the embedded browser is outdated. However, while looking around the internet, I found some information from a different project but one that also uses embedded browsers. Apparently you can work around this Google block by changing the useragent to that of a more up to date version of Chrome.

So since Steam has no way to change the useragent via its UI, I wanted to know if I could maybe set up a local VPN that will do the spoofing. Is this even a thing that can be done? If so, how?